# Multiple types as single generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics

There is an abstract class and interface:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public void DoFoo();
}
public interface IBar
{
     void DoBar();
}
```

I have multiple classes inherited from Foo, but not all of them implement IBar. I can declare generic class that will be constrainted to both Foo and IBar, like this:

```
public class Test<T> where T : Foo, IBar
{
    public List<T> ListOfFooThatImplementsIBar;
}
```

But I want to define a simple collection, that will be constrainted to both Foo and IBar, something like this:

```
List<Foo and IBar> myList = new List<Foo and IBar>();
```

Is there a way to do this nicely in C#?

Comment: Why would you want a list of things that don't have any relationship (common methods/properties) with each other? You might as well use a `List<object>`.

Comment: @itsme86 Good point - I'm not sure what the use-case here is.  T will only be accessible as an `IFoo` (with my example), which has nothing.  If Valery wanted to determine if `T` is `Foo` or `IBar`, they would have to [safe-cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as) and check for null.

Comment: You might need to go with something like `MyList<T> : IList<T> where T : Foo, IBar` and use `List<T>` as an implementation detail.

Comment: Never mind. @EricLippert cleared up the intent in his comment to one of the answers. I had interpreted the question to be about union typing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost. If you really want this, why can't you just sub-class `List<T>`, as in `class ListFooAndIBar<T> : List<T> where T : Foo, IBar { }`? I can see why it'd be a nice feature to have in the language, but I'm not following why what you want isn't at least in a practical way possible?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9037577/can-i-define-constrain-a-member-as-implementing-two-interfaces-without-generics. In the way that really matters, it's actually exactly the same question -- i.e. how to declare a type that is essentially the intersection of two other types -- but it's asked in a different way. There are some other work-arounds suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this nicely in C#?

No.

The feature you want is called "[intersection types](https://kwangyulseo.com/2015/06/09/thoughts-on-intersection-types/)". C# only supports intersection types in "where" clauses. That has always struck me as slightly odd.

Also odd: I talk with the designer of the C# generic type system *every day*, and I've never thought to ask him what design principles led to having intersection types in only one place. Maybe I'll fix that tomorrow!

A number of languages support intersection types to a greater or lesser extent -- Hack and Flow come to mind. Interestingly, both of those use flow-based typing. Intersection and union types are in many ways a natural fit for flow-based typing.

Comment: Thanks Eric. Your answer is pretty much straight and helpful!

Comment: @Eric Lippert, OT, who is the designer of the C# generic type system? Did he also move to FB? ;)

Comment: @SolutionYogi: Andrew Kennedy, and yes; we work together on Hack.

Answer (score 1):

As @EricLippert answered, there is no way to make it excactly as I want. There are several workaround to this issue:

1. make common interface to both Foo and IBar (may not be applicable if Foo class is a third party one and you can't affect their sources, as in my case)
2. use raw list as List< object> and perform runtime casting when needed (which may degrade the performance).

I choose the third one that best suited my needs:

```
public List<(Foo, IBar)> ListOfFooThatImplementsIBar;

public void Add<T>(T item) where T : Foo, IBar { ListOfFooThatImplementsIBar.Add((item, item)); }
```

So I can use Item1 when I need interact with Foo, Item2 to interact with IBar.
Hope my answer helps!